# Run a function as far as a variable reaches specific values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a canvas game which calls a function incScore every time an action is performed in the game to increase the score.

Inside incScore I have a few if statements to draw a particular image to represent a level number on the canvas.

I also want to have a sound play once per level up. The way I've gone about things the lvlup sound will play every time the score matches the if statement.

Can anyone please help me get this so that the sound will only play once when the level changes and not again until the next level change? I'm also mention I'm using jQuery incase it has anything that could help me.

```
incScore(); //everytime an action in the game causes the score to increase

function incScore(){


    if (scoreTotal < 500){
        lvlimg = "L01";
        drawLevel(lvlimg);
        lvlupSound();
    }

    else if (scoreTotal > 500  && scoreTotal < 1000){
        lvlimg = "L02";
        drawLevel(lvlimg);
        lvlupSound();
    }

    else{
        lvlimg = "L03";
        drawLevel(lvlimg);
        lvlupSound();
    }
}
```

Comment: The title is misleading. Shouldn't it rather read "Run function if a value changes at specific values"

Comment: @try-catch-finally You can click the "edit" link and change the title. You even gain more reputation if the edit is accepted after review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could shorten your function and use a semi static property to save the state. Using that, you can compare the current level to the previous and play a sound if they differ.

```
function incScore(){
        incScore.level = incScore.level || 'L0'; //< initialize property
        lvlimg = "L0" + scoreTotal < 500 ? 1 : scoreTotal < 1000 ? 2 : 3; 
        drawLevel(lvlimg);
        if (incScore.level!=='L0' && 
            incScore.level !== lvlimg) { lvlupSound(); };
        //  ^compare local level to current
        incScore.level = lvlimg;
        //             ^ update local level
}
```

[**edit**, based on comment] The third line is a so called *ternary*, or *conditional operator*. See [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). You can use more conditions.

To avoid playing a sound before the score has reached a first level, you could use
`if (incScore.level!=='L0' && incScore.level !== lvlimg)`.

I've created a [**mockup jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/NRAEC/)

Comment: thanks for that, I'm sorta having problems with the 3rd line I think it's a little advanced for me. I have 20 levels so firstly I abandoned the L0 prefix and renamed the images accordingly. But I don't know how to apply my level thresholds to that line. level 1 scoreTotal > 500, level 2 scoreTotal > 500 && scoreTotal < 20000, level 3 scoreTotal > 20000 && scoreTotal < 50000 and so on... and also how to avoid playing the sound for the first level.

Comment: @Kooilnc thanks for that, it has also highlighted how inefficient my code is! One question though what do i need to reset at games end to stop the levelup sound playing immediately in a follow up game?

Comment: You can reset incScore.level: I've adjusted the jsfiddle to demonstrate that (@ http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/NRAEC/).

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution could be comparing the current level to the old one, to detect when the level changed:

```
function scoreToLevel(score)
    if(score < 500){
        return 1
    }else if (score < 1000){
        return 2
    }else{
        return 3
    }
}

function incScore()
    var next_level = scoreToLevel(scoreTotal)
    if(next_level !== current_level){
        lvlimg = "L0" + next_level;
        drawLevel(lvlimg)
        lvlupSound()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to factor the sound out of those if statements.  If the levels are nice and regular like that(every 500 points) and the points always increase in a way that you will always land exactly on an even multiple of 500 when you level up, something like this should do:

```
if(scoreTotal % 500 === 0 && scoreTotal < 1001)
{
    lvlupSound();
}
```

If you won't always land directly on the gate to the next level(maybe the player can earn anywhere between 1 and 15 points at a time) then you should be able to get by using something along the lines of this before you increment the player's score:

```
if( (scoreTotal % 500) > ((scoreTotal + increment) % 500)
{
    lvlupSound();
}
```

if your level boundries are not regular like that obviously it gets a little bit more complex, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have the in every statement for every score (which means from 0 to infinite).

You will need to write inner if statements such as;

```
if (scoreTotal < 500){
        lvlimg = "L01";
        drawLevel(lvlimg);
        if(scoreTotal x times of each the level) // That means for each level completed
{
        lvlupSound();

}
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your score increment is only 1, then only play the tone when the score equals the threshold for a new level.

If they can increase their score by more than 1, then you could pass the number of points in and check the score before and after to see if the numbers fall on each side of the threshold.

If that still doesn't work, some more info on the "level" and points would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes the score is a lot greater than one, it's calculated by a number for a particular event multiplied by the level number. But I see what you are saying - if I get the score before and if the score after breaks a threshold then the sound plays.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Like Taicho says, having the `lvlupSound()` in every leg of the if/else statement is why it always plays. However, I think you still need to tweak it to only play when `oldScore < lvlThreshold && newScore >= lvlThreshold`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/k7AWe/3/)):

```
var scoreTotal,
  lastLevel = 0,
  levels = [500, 1000, 2500, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 75000],
  currentLevel = 0,
  lvlImg;

function incScore() {
  while (scoreTotal > levels[currentLevel]) {
    currentLevel++;
  }
  if (lastLevel !== currentLevel) {
    lastLevel = currentLevel;
    // gives a two digit number with a leading zero
    lvlImg = ('0' + currentLevel).slice(-2);
    drawLevel("L" + lvlimg);
    lvlupSound();
  }
}
```

Then you can easily add additional levels by adding the score cutoff to the `levels` variable.